# State Based vs Passing Arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, state

I'm using Python as an example.

```
class ThingArguments:
    def render(self, text, color):
        return magiclibrary.generateText(text, color)


class ThingStates:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)

    def render(self, text):
        return magiclibrary.generateText(text, self.color)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

Which is more acceptable for Python? Which one is more preferable for any language? What are the advantages over each..?

Comment: If you don't need state, how about simply using a function?  Less state is always an advantage, as long as you can get away with it.

Comment: External state is an implicit input to functions, which often makes debugging harder.  State is also a pain for unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [as Sven Marnach mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943154/state-based-vs-passing-arguments#comment19226857_13943154), the first example should be a plain function:

```
def render(self, text, color):
    return magiclibrary.generateText(text, color)
```

So what's the difference between this plain function and the class solution?

### Plain Function

- easy to document and understand
- trivial to test (just make many calls in a row and compare the outputs to the expected)
- simpler mental model, leading to less surprises and bugs
- keeps text and color on the same place, so you always know which color will be used

### Class

- can be extended, leading to additional behavior transparently
- can be passed as argument and other places can call `render` without specifying a color (important if this is the most common behavior)

In Python the first method is usually preferred. A plain function means less state to worry about and this can be a big deal for larger or trickier programs. Also, [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

I always prefer the first method, even when not exactly available. Java comes to mind, where functions must always be contained inside a class, so I end up with many static functions in abstract classes.

I think it's more a question of context than language. The class would be preferable if it were for rendering a log, for example, where the functions calling it couldn't care less about the color. On the other hand, if most callers knew about the color and wanted to choose it, the class would be a no-no.

And as always, when in doubt take the simpler route. It's easier to complicate your code than simplify.